# C++ : Data retrieved from MySQL table in win32 applications

Tags: c++, mysql, winapi, unicode

I'm trying to retrieve data from a MySQL database using MySQL Connector/C.
Everything is fine, except all data I recieve is complete gibberish :)

Here is my code for the mysql connection and data receiving:

```
void mysql_connect(HWND hwnd) {

MYSQL mysql;
mysql_init(&mysql);

mysql_real_connect(&mysql, "localhost", "root", "", "thetable", 3306, NULL, 0);

mysql_query(&mysql, "SELECT name, pass FROM users ORDER BY id ASC");

MYSQL_RES *res = mysql_store_result(&mysql);

if (res == NULL) 
{
    wchar_t err[64];
    swprintf(err, 64, L"%p", mysql_error(&mysql));
    MessageBox(NULL, err, L"Error", (UINT) MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    mysql_close(&mysql);
    return;
}

int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(res);

MYSQL_ROW row;

while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res))) 
{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < num_fields; i++) 
    {
        wchar_t r[128];
        swprintf(r, 128, L"%p", row[i]);
        MessageBox(NULL, r, L"Data", (UINT) MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    } 
}

mysql_free_result(res);
mysql_close(&mysql);

}
```

After roaming the internet for countless of mancycles I aquired the knowledge that I should convert the data from widechars to < the-thing-you-convert-it-to >, since I'm compiling in unicode.

All my MySQL tables are currently encoded in utf8_unicode_ci.

Example string I could receive from the program: 0108F164

So what should I do to get the data in the appropriate manner?

Oh, and the data received shows correctly if I compile in ansi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, it sounds like MySQL is returning UTF-8 strings, which you are interpreting as UTF-16 strings.  You need to run it through [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert UTF8 to UTF-16.

```
MYSQL_ROW row;

while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res))) 
{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < num_fields; i++) 
    {
        wchar_t r[128];
        if (MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, row[i], -1, r, ARRAYSIZE(r)) != 0)
        {
            // success!
            MessageBox(NULL, r, L"Data", (UINT) MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }
        else
        {
             DWORD err = GetLastError();
             swprintf(r, 128, L"Error %x", err);
             MessageBox(NULL, r, L"Error", (UINT) MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: It appears as if MultiByteToWideChar returns 0 all of the time. Using that piece of code doesn't create a single MessageBox for me. There are 5 entries in the mysql table.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja If MBTWC does return 0, GetLastError() will be set.  What does it display?

Comment: I was just doing that actually. The error is 1004: invalid flags

Comment: Try 0 instead of MB_PRECOMPOSED.